# Why does the listview display the items incorrectly after I remove them in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

[image]

Firstscreen with all the notes.

[image]

After I deleted the first note!

I have recently started programming with .NET MAUI. The elements are correctly removed in the C# list. However, after deleting the remaining elements are only partially displayed. That means that only e.g. the 4th element is displayed. For the other elements only an empty bar is displayed.

My code so far:
XAML:

```
<VerticalStackLayout>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>


                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Image
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Source="logo.png"
                        WidthRequest="150"
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        VerticalOptions="Start"/>

                    <Label
                        TextColor="Black"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Text="TODO"
                        FontSize="35"
                        HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                        VerticalOptions="Start" 
                        Margin="23"/>


                </Grid>





                <Grid BackgroundColor="#24D4A3">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ListView 
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                    RowHeight="100"
                    x:Name="listview">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate >
                            <ViewCell >

                                    <Grid BackgroundColor="#24D4A3">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Button BackgroundColor="#DEABF5"
                                            Text="{Binding Title}"  
                                            Clicked="onNoteSelected"
                                            BorderWidth="2"
                                            TextColor="Black"
                                            FontSize="28"
                                            Margin="20"
                                            CornerRadius="100"
                                            WidthRequest="350"
                                            HeightRequest="70"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                            VerticalOptions="Start"/>


                                        <Button
                                            BindingContext="{Binding Id}"
                                            Clicked="ToDoSolved" 
                                            BorderWidth="2"
                                            BorderColor="Black"
                                            BackgroundColor="White"
                                            WidthRequest="45"
                                            HeightRequest="45"
                                            CornerRadius="35" 
                                            Margin="0,0,260,0" 
                                            />
                                    </Grid>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>

                    <ImageButton  
                                Clicked="Settings"
                                Source="settings.png"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                BorderColor="#2b3c3c" 
                                BorderWidth="0" 
                                BackgroundColor="#34A4EB" 
                                CornerRadius="35" 
                                HorizontalOptions="End" 
                                WidthRequest="70" 
                                HeightRequest="70" 
                                Margin="0,10, 10, 0" 
                                VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                        <ImageButton 
                                Clicked="CreateNote"
                                Source="add.png"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                BorderColor="#2b3c3c" 
                                BorderWidth="0" 
                                BackgroundColor="#34A4EB" 
                                CornerRadius="35" 
                                HorizontalOptions="End" 
                                WidthRequest="70" 
                                HeightRequest="70" 
                                Margin="0,0,10,10" 
                                Padding="2,0,0,0"/>
                    </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
```

C#:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    { 

    private ObservableCollection<Note> notes = new ObservableCollection<Note>();
    public ObservableCollection<Note> Notes 
    {
        get { return notes; }
        set { notes = value; }
    }
    public MainPage()   
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        notes.Add(new Note(1, "My Note1", "I'm ugly"));
        notes.Add(new Note(2, "My Note2", "I'm short"));
        notes.Add(new Note(3, "My Note3", "I'm smart"));
        notes.Add(new Note(4, "My Note4", "I'm smart"));
        //notes.Add(new Note(6, "My Note6", "I'm smart"));
        //notes.Add(new Note(7, "My Note7", "I'm smart"));
        //notes.Add(new Note(8, "My Note8", "I'm smart"));
        //notes.Add(new Note(9, "My Note9", "I'm smart"));
        this.BindingContext= Notes;
        listview.ItemsSource= Notes;
        
    }

    private async void CreateNote(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//CreateNote");
    }

    private async void Settings(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Settings");
    }

 

    private void ToDoSolved(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button= (Button) sender ;
        
        var id = (int)button.BindingContext;
         
        var item = Notes.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        if (item != null) 
        {
            Notes.Remove(item);
            Console.WriteLine(id);
        }
    
    }

    async void onNoteSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button= (Button) sender ;

        var id = (int)button.BindingContext;

        //await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("NotePage" + id);
    }
}
```

I would be grateful for any help :)

Comment: the `LIst<Note>` in `MainPage` needs to be an `ObservableCollection<Note>`.  The `ObservableCollection` inside of the `Notes` class does not serve any purpose and should be removed.  In order to update an **existing note**, the `Note` class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or inherit from `ObservableObject`

Comment: Okay i will try the steps you mentioned, thank you very much!

Comment: also, if you are binding `ItemsSource` in XAML do NOT also assign it in code.  Pick one approach or the other

Comment: Okay it works well, but the Item have been removed in a random way. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: There is no need to call Refresh()

Comment: Okay the method and the refreshview has been deleted. Thx

Comment: The items are not display rightly. Sometimes the items are in the List, but they cannot be mapped successfully. Please help me

Comment: I have no idea what that means.  You need to be specific about the problem you're having if you expect to help

Comment: The elements are correctly removed in the C# list. However, after deleting the remaining elements are only partially displayed. That means that only e.g. the 4th element is displayed. For the other elements only an empty bar is displayed.

Comment: Please add to question a new section, that shows the code changes you have made. Also, I don't understand what you intend to do in this line: `BindingContext = Notes;`. That will not help the listview work, and it will break the other bindings, such as `{Binding IsRefreshing}`. Probably should be `BindingContext = this;`, unless `RefreshCommand` is in a viewmodel, in which case it should be that viewmodel.

Comment: Also, note class is just a pure model, you should add property public int Id { get; set; } as you do and avoid adding `public ObservableCollection<Note> ob_notes = new ObservableCollection<Note>();`.

Answer (score 2):

To delete the item, since you are using `ListView`, you can delete the via
Button click. However, you need to delete the item from bottom to top in order.

**Code-behind:**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
{

    

    public ObservableCollection<Note> Notes { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<Note>();



    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AddNotes();

        BindingContext = this;
    }

    private void AddNotes()
    {
        Notes.Add(new Note("0", "My Note1"));
        Notes.Add(new Note("1", "My Note2"));
        Notes.Add(new Note("2", "My Note3"));
        Notes.Add(new Note("3", "My Note4"));
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var note = (Button)sender;


        Note listnote = (from itm in Notes
                         where itm.Id == note.CommandParameter.ToString()

                         select itm).FirstOrDefault<Note>();

        Notes.Remove(listnote);
    }


}
```

**Xaml:**

```
        <VerticalStackLayout>

            <ScrollView>

                <StackLayout>

                    <Grid>

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <RowDefinition />

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <ColumnDefinition />

                            <ColumnDefinition />

                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>



                        <Image

                    Grid.Column="0"

                    Source="logo.png"

                    WidthRequest="150"

                    HorizontalOptions="Start"

                    VerticalOptions="Start"

               />



                        <Label

                    TextColor="Black"

                    Grid.Column="1"

                    Text="TODO"

                    FontSize="35"

                    HorizontalOptions="Start"

                    VerticalOptions="Start"

                    Margin="23"

                    

                    />



                    </Grid>



                    <Grid BackgroundColor="#24D4A3">

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <RowDefinition />

                            <RowDefinition />

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <ColumnDefinition />

                            <ColumnDefinition />

                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>



                        <ListView

                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"

                Grid.RowSpan="2"

                RowHeight="100"

                 x:Name="listview"

                ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}" >

                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                                <DataTemplate >
                                    <ViewCell>

                                 

                                        <Grid BackgroundColor="#24D4A3" >

                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>

                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>

                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            <Button BackgroundColor="#DEABF5"

                                        Text="{Binding Title}"

                                        BorderWidth="2"

                                        TextColor="Black"

                                        FontSize="28"

                                        Margin="20"

                                        CornerRadius="100"

                                        WidthRequest="350"

                                        HeightRequest="70"

                                        HorizontalOptions="Center"

                                        VerticalOptions="Start"/>


                                                                                   
                                     <Button

                                      

                                       Text="Delete"
                                          Clicked="Button_Clicked"
                                         CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"

                                        BorderWidth="2"

                                        BorderColor="Black"

                                        BackgroundColor="White"

                                       WidthRequest="45"

                                        HeightRequest="45"

                                        CornerRadius="35"

                                        Margin="0,0,260,0"

                                        />


                                        </Grid>

                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>

                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                        </ListView>

                    </Grid>

                </StackLayout>

            </ScrollView>

        </VerticalStackLayout>
```

**Note:**

```
 public class Note 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Note(string id, string title)
    {
         Id = id;
         Title = title;
     }
     
}
```

Comment: @Der Illuminate HD You've edited your question and it's different than the one you edited before. I'll update my post if possible.

Comment: @Der Illuminate HD you can see my update.

Answer (score 0):

**[Workaround]**
For anyone who have same issue and is willing to change ListView for something else what works, than here is solution:

<ListView> to **<CollectionView>**

<ListView.ItemTemplate> to **<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>**

After that It worked perfectly and in order to make it look more like ListView I haved added element  **<Line> </Line>** to each item in CollectionView which will be showned.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue with you, I think it's a bug in MAUI, it works fine in Xamarin.
My **Workaround** is put the list view into a StackLayout or ScrollView without any attribute

```
<StackLayout><ListView>.....</ListView><StackLayout>
```

when I got the issue, I put VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" in the StackLayout, after removing the attribute, it works fine now